# What frequencies will get lost/diminished when you listen to a colloidal speaker without the backside

Tags: acoustics

I was checking the connections of my colloidal speakers, so I had to listen to music without the backside of the speakers. There was clearly a difference in the quality of the music, but I couldn't tell which frequencies were diminished by taking the backside away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speakers are designed with a combination of filters that help correct for any resonance that is provided by the enclosure. When you take the back off, you change the resonance - so you will end up with "colored" sound. Usually, it is the lower frequencies that suffer, but without details about the actual enclosure it's hard to give a definite answer. See [this link](http://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Tutorial/SpeakerBox/) for an example of the calculations that go into enclosure design.